# How to open the application( installed by macports) with argument in the terminal

Tags: emacs, terminal, macports, tex

My os is Macosx 10.10

I install okular by macports.
I can open the program by using `open -a okular`
But when I use `open -a okular --unique Homework_20151023.pdf#src:88Homework_20151023.tex` Nothing happens, why?

Update:2015-10-25

I found the okular is in the "/Applications/MacPorts/KDE4/okular.app/Contents/MacOS/okular".

Then.
I aliased the okular in zsh. `alias okular="/Applications/MacPorts/KDE4/okular.app/Contents/MacOS/okular"`.
It's ok to just use `okular ***.pdf`. But still `okular --unique Homework_20151023.pdf#src:88Homework_20151023.tex` is useless in emacs.

Comment: Why is there an Emacs tag?

Comment: In emacs, I set `“Tex View Program List”` with `open -a okular –unique %o#src:%n%b`. But it is useless

Comment: Is your macports `bin` directory in the PATH that AUCTeX uses?  Is there any error message in the `*Messages*` buffer?

Comment: There is no error message. And I also add `/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"` into path. But I found the okular is in the "/Applications/MacPorts/KDE4/okular.app/Contents/MacOS/okular". 

Then.
I aliased the okular in zsh. `alias okular="/Applications/MacPorts/KDE4/okular.app/Contents/MacOS/okular"`.
It's ok to just use `okular ***.pdf`. But still `okular --unique Homework_20151023.pdf#src:88Homework_20151023.tex` is useless in emacs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
open -a okular --args --unique Homework_20151023.pdf#src:88Homework_20151023.tex
```

otherwise the arguments are interpreted (and ignored) by `open` instead of being passed on to `okular`.

See also the man page of open:

```
man open
```